# Why is Java Servlet response.Redirect causing browser to parse requested HTML as URL

Tags: java, servlets, session-state, response.redirect

I am attempting to send a response redirect at the end of a Java servlet post request:

```
session.setAttribute("token", token);
String redirectUrl = response.encodeRedirectURL(MYSITE_URL + "extras.html");
response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl)
```

Stepping through the code redirectUrl equates to `"http://localhost:8080/mysite/extras.html"`.  The browswer however is attempting to request the following url, which to the observant is acutally the html of the document I'm requesting.

```
http://localhost:8080/mysite/%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%20%3Chtml%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Chead%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EBet%20Ya%20Friends%3C/title%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20name=%22viewport%22%20content=%22width=device-width,%20initial-scale=1%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css%22%20/%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%20src=%22http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%20src=%22http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%20%20%20%20%3C/head%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbody%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20data-role=%22page%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20data-role=%22header%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%3EBet%20Ya%20Friends%3C/h1%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%3C!--%20/header%20--%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%20data-role=%22listview%22%20data-inset=%22true%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Cdiv%3EView%20Friends%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20class=%22ui-li-count%22%3E6%3C/span%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3ECanary%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3ECat%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EDog%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EGerbil%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EIguana%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EMouse%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/ul%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Cdiv%3EMake%20A%20Bet%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20class=%22ui-li-count%22%3E6%3C/p%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EChicken%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3ECow%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EDuck%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EHorse%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EPig%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3ESheep%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/ul%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Cdiv%3EBet%20History%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20class=%22ui-li-count%22%3E18%3C/p%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EAardvark%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EAlligator%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EAnt%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EBear%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EBeaver%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3ECougar%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EDingo%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EEagle%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EElephant%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EFerret%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EFrog%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EGiraffe%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3ELion%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EMonkey%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EPanda%20bear%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EPolar%20bear%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3ETiger%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=%22index.html%22%3EZebra%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/ul%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/ul%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%3C!--%20/page%20--%3E%3C!--%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href=%22#%22%20onclick=%22getUserFriends%28%29;%22%3EGet%20friends%3C/a%3E%3Cbr%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id=%22user-friends%22%3E%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20function%20getUserFriends%28%29%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FB.api%28%27/me/friends&fields=name,picture%27,%20function%28response%29%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%28%27Got%20friends:%20%27,%20response%29;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28!response.error%29%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20markup%20=%20%27%27;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20friends%20=%20response.data;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20%28var%20i=0;%20i%20%3C%20friends.length%20&&%20i%20%3C%2025;%20i++%29%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20friend%20=%20friends[i];%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20markup%20+=%20%27%3Cimg%20src=%22%27%20+%20friend.picture%20+%20%27%22%3E%20%27%20+%20friend.name%20+%20%27%3Cbr%3E%27;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20}%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.getElementById%28%27user-friends%27%29.innerHTML%20=%20markup;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20}%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20}%29;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20}%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/script%3E--%3E%20%20%20%20%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E
```

My question is, why? Why is the actual html document being requested rather than the url? And why is encodeURL not encoding the session in the URL?

Comment: the encodeRedirectURL also encode the sessionId into the url when necessary, maybe your session is storing this html content, try cleaning the session before encoding the url to see if it still encode the html document

Comment: @sMaM, did you monitor the network traffic in your browser? Is the first 30x response sent to the browser correct?

Comment: Check the URL again. Is it a typo? It starts with "html:", not "http:".

Comment: What value is MYSITE_URL. Can you output/log it just before you call String redirectUrl = response.encodeRedirectURL(MYSITE_URL + "extras.html");

Comment: sorry html is a typo on SO not in browser

Comment: MYSITE_URL is a public static final string "http://localhost:8080/mysite/"

Comment: Several days later, I can no longer replicate the problem, so the issue is solved however the problem remains unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that MYSITE_URL is

> `"localhost:8080/mysite/"`

. That could be the problem. Its missing http in the beginning. Can you modify MYSITE_URL to

> `"http://localhost:8080/mysite/"`

and then try ?

Comment: Sorry, it already is. I must have entered my latest comment incorrectly, or SO wont show the "http://" thinking it a live link